# Translate a rectangle but keep within bounds

Tags: geometry

In x,y space, given a coordinate P that is within bounds 0,0,bWidth,bHeight and a rectangle r where r has width rWidth and rHeight (and rWidth<=bWidth and rHeight<=bHeight), present an algorithm that would return the coordinates of a rectangle T such that T has the same width and height of r and is contained in the bounds and is as close to centered around P as possible.

ie, if p is top left point, then T would be in the top left, but if P is in middle, so is T.

is there any way of doing this without having to do a bunch of if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x$ coordinate of the center of the translated rectangle should ideally be $P_x$, but must be at least $\frac{\mathit{rWidth}}2$ and at most $\mathit{bWidth}-\frac{\mathit{rWidth}}2$:

$$ C_x = \min(\max(P_x,\frac{\mathit{rWidth}}2),\mathit{bWidth}-\frac{\mathit{rWidth}}2)$$

Similarly for the $y$ coordinate.

Of course, the $\min$ and $\max$ have conditionals hidden within them, e.g.:
$$\min(a,b) = \begin{cases}a & \text{if } a<b \\ b & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
There's no real way around this for getting the necessary sharp edges in the output. If you really want, you can disguise the conditionals using absolute values:
$$ \min(a,b) = \frac{a+b-|a-b|}2 $$
but that will just make the expressions impenetrable without really buying you anything valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You only need four if statements as far as I can tell. In pseudocode,

```
rX = pX - rWidth/2;
rY = pY - rHeight/2;

if(rX < 0){
    rX = 0;
}
else if(rX + rWidth > bWidth){
    rX -= (rX + rWidth) - bWidth;
}

if(rY < 0){
    rY = 0;
}
else if(rY + rHeight > bHeight){
    rY -= (rY + rHeight) - bHeight;
}
```

rX, rY are coordinates of the corner of the rectangle closest to the origin. (Top left in computer graphics, lower left in the first quadrant of an XY graph)

I think that if statements like this are very common in graphics computing, although I am not an expert.